# Using microwaves to dry a small sample of material - best method?

Tags: microwave, waveguide

We have a requirement to use microwaves (no choice here) to dry a small sample of material with a mass not exceeding one gram. It will be placed in a small sealed steel enclosure. First thoughts were to use a magnetron from a microwave oven and plumb in the waveguide to the enclosure. That was, of course, somewhat insane given the power levels.

The chamber itself is a cylinder approximately 90mm tall and 50mm diameter and the microwave guide needs to come in through the wall. So maybe a coax cable from a 2.4GHz power amplifier feeding a stub?

I estimate that something like 20W should be sufficient.

So, has anyone done anything like this or have any suggestions?

Comment: I remember a demo booth from a high-frequency university institute trying to entice students. They popped a single corn (of popcorn) in a cylindrical cavity (iirc, slightly smaller than yours) while it fell through. :) Don't think this helps you implement that, but it suggests it's doable.